# ListView overlapping TabLayout and button when used in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I want to use a `ListView` inside a fragment, there are swipeable tabs at the top. These tabs are overlapped by the `ListView` and also the app crashes when I try to swipe between tabs.

This is how it looks:

[Screenshot_overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck4SC.png)

I've been trying all day to search for a solution, but haven't found one that worked for me... Since it's my first question here, I'm really trying to be as understandable as I can with what I want (and if you need anything else the project is on Git [here](https://github.com/Sara59/MAMN01)) .

I used `CoordinatorLayout` for the fragment that should inflate, but I read that `ListView` and that layout did not work well together, so now I just want to get it to work with `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. I also tried to use the `RecyclerView` but that didn't work either.

I've also tried changing between `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` wherever I could. So now I wanted to hear if someone could help me. Below is how the code looks for now.

**activity_main.xml**
*-where tabs and viewpager has their views*

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**workout_list_layout.xml**
*-where listlayout is set*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_workout.xml**
*-a fragment that should show the list below the tabs*

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_list"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/workoutList">

    <include layout="@layout/workout_list_layout"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add_workout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/workoutList"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start_workout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/workoutList"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PageFragment.java**
*-handles all fragments*

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view;
    if(mPage == 1){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout, container, false);

        WorkoutListFragment workoutListFragment = (WorkoutListFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("workoutlistfragment");
        if (workoutListFragment == null){
            workoutListFragment = new WorkoutListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, workoutListFragment,"workoutlistfragment");
            transaction.commit();
        }


        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_start_workout);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.button_start_workout:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TimerWindow.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }else if(mPage == 2){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_performance, container, false);
    }else{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false);
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

**WorkoutListFragment.java**
*-listfragment that inflates the view*

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); //List items

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_list_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id){
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    TextView textView =  (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" , "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItems(String workoutTitle, View v) {
    listItems.add(workoutTitle);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are trying to replace your "android.R.id.content" with your fragment. But android.R.id.content is not really part of your layout. Instead you should create a placeholder layout for your fragments, under your tabs and over your viewpager, in your main activity xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your PageFragment.java, replace (don't add) your placeholder with your fragment, like this:

```
    WorkoutListFragment workoutListFragment = (WorkoutListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("workoutlistfragment");
            if (workoutListFragment == null) {
                workoutListFragment = new WorkoutListFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, workoutListFragment).commit();
            }
```

let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have to work on your layout files to sort your view properly. Set "ViewPager" below the "TabLayout" by "android:layout_below" attribute in your "activity_main.xml". And similarly in "fragment_workout.xml" change the LinearLayout's "android:layout_height" attribute value to "wrap_content" and the "button_start_workout" attribute "android:layout_above" to "android:layout_below" in the same file. That should do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it and it did not work...

Here's how it looks now:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5J-MYgiEYRwNHVSR1VhY2hKR1k

Any other ideas?